# Linked list always show empty

Tags: c, data-structures

> **REQUIREMENT / QUESTION 2**
>   In computing, the process identifier (normally referred to as the process ID or PID), is a number used by most operating system kernels, to uniquely identify an active process. The PIDs are usually allocated on a sequential basis, beginning with 0 and rising to a maximum value that varies from system to system. Create a link list to store the PIDs. To create a new PID, `createPID()` function is used.
>
> Each PID is inserted into the list at the beginning of the list, using `insertPID()` function. Once a process is completed, that particular PID is deleted, using the `deletePID()` function.
>
> The assessment will be done based on the following criteria:
>
> 1. A proper writing of C codes and its structure
> 2. The ability of program to be compiled and executed
> 3. Implementation of correct programming techniques
> 4. Complete documentation and correct submission
>
> Note: You must write C programming codes for this assignment.

I already create a code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};

void createPID ();
void insertPID (struct node *start,int x);
struct node * deletePID (struct node * start,int x);
void displayPID(struct node *start);
struct node * start;

int main()
{
    createPID();
    insertPID(start,0);
    insertPID(start,1);
    insertPID(start,2);
    displayPID(start);
    start=deletePID(start, 3);
    displayPID(start);

}

void createPID(){
    struct node *start = NULL;
}


void displayPID(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *p;
    if(start == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;

    }
    printf("List is :");
    p=start;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",p->info);
        p=p->link;
     } 
     printf("\n");
}
/*End of displayList()*/

void insertPID(struct node * start, int data)
{
    struct node *temp,*p;

    p=start;
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
        if(p->link==NULL)
        break;
        p=p->link;
    }
    temp=(struct node *)malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    temp->info=data;
    if(p==NULL)
    start=temp;
    else
    {
    temp->link= p->link;
    p->link= temp;
    }
}

struct node* deletePID(struct node * start,int x){
    struct node *temp, *p;
    if(start == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return start;
    }
    /*Deletion of first node */
    if(start->info == x)
    {
        temp=start;
        start= start->link;
        free(temp);
        return start;
    }

    /*Deletion in between or at the end */
    p=start;
    while (p->link != NULL)
    {
        if (p-> link -> info== x)
        break;
        p=p->   link;
    }
    if(p->link==NULL)
    printf("Element %d not in list \n\n",x);
    else 
    {
        temp=p->link;
        p->link=temp->link;
        free (temp);
    }
    return start;

}
```

The result always empty list. Need help to figure out what is the problem ?

Comment: If you want to modify `start` inside `insertPID` you need to pass it by pointer (`node** start` pointer to pointer). Now you modify local variable, so global `start` is never changed and it is always `NULL`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is in `insertPID` function. `start` as argument of function is local variable, it hides global `start` and the line below

```
start = temp;
```

only modifies local `start`, global `start` is not affected and it is always NULL.

If you want to update `start` pointer you need to pass it by pointer-to-pointer:

```
void insertPID (struct node **start,int x);
//...
insertPID(&start,0);
insertPID(&start,1);
insertPID(&start,2);
//...
void insertPID(struct node ** start, int data)
{
    //...
    p=*start;
    //...
    if(p==NULL)
        *start=temp;
    //...
}
```

---

```
void createPID(){
    struct node *start = NULL;
}
```

I assume this function wants to set `start` (global) to 0 ? So it should be:

```
void createPID(){
    start = NULL;
}
```

Your version introduces local `start` variable, so global is not affected.

But the call of `createPID` is superfluous here because `start` as global variable is initialized to 0 before `main` starts executing.

Comment: Can i put the struct node * start inside int main(){} to avoid global variable. i am not familiar with pointer of pointer.

Comment: To avoid *pointer-to-pointer* you need to have `start` as global variable, then remove all `start` from params function in `deletePID`, `insertPID` etc. and then you can just access `start` as global - it is visible inside the body of these functions. But, if you put `start` inside main, then you have to use pointer-to-pointer technique to modify `start` inside `insertPID`.

Comment: I am Malaysian. If you are free, Can I whatapps you? My Whatapps number is +60127905089. I got some sample wanna share with you to identify my problem. Sorry for bad grammar. I try to remove all parameter with struct node * start, but the app still not working and declare it outside int main(){},

Comment: @Teo I don't use whatapps, you can put your whole code for example on [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) then click `share` and put the link here, I will see where the problem is. And maybe I will be able to help you to solve this.

Comment: This file can be also found using the Coliru command line: cat /Archive2/80/20fac4149aa205/main.cpp

Comment: weird. It works. Why it din work inside dev compiler?

Comment: You have another bug , in `insertPID` should be `if(p==NULL) { start=temp; start->link = NULL; }`, you need to set `link` to NULL for first created item (I added the second line in `{}` block). Without this you will have an infinite loop. Change it and test again in Dev compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. You are angel. But why it runs in Coliru?

Comment: Some kind of undefined behaviour, hard to tell why it executed without crash.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks a lot. Big genius.